# Can a file be both valid HTML and valid RSS with the same content?

Tags: html, rss

I would like to build a simple static blog that contains many articles.  For technical reasons related to the hosting environment, I don't want to use a static site builder like Jekyll.

To simplify development, I would like to place the index of the blog in only a single file.  Ideally, this file would be both valid HTML for rendering by web browsers and valid RSS for scraping by feed readers.  Is this technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't.

You can provide RSS with a stylesheet to allow it to be rendered in a web browser (for example, FeedBurner do this and they host [the Google Online Security Blog](http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoogleOnlineSecurityBlog)), but HTML and RSS are different markup up languages.

Comment: Is it possible to include javascript within RSS to dynamically generate the stylesheet?

Comment: Also, is it okay to keep the RSS file named `index.html` so that it is the default page?